# how to compile .NET code to 32 bits on a 64 bit machine

Tags: compilation, x86, assemblies, 64-bit, jit

I am developing and deploying on 64 bit computers.  Unfortunately, due to a bug in the 64 bit JIT compiler that has existed and remains unfixed by Microsoft since the introduction of the .NET 64 bit version, my code scales quadratically and breaks. Here is a link to the documentation on the bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/508748  The old 32 bit compiler works fine. I need to compile one dll to 32 bits and make sure it runs as 32 bits.

In the workarounds someone has written:

> Since Microsoft has not figured out in 3 years how to create a < 400MB
>   image from a 20K XSLT compiled transform script we have been surviving
>   by setting the assemblies that are implementing any XSLT
>   transformation to 32 bit.

How is that done? Thanks!

Note: I need this to compile a regex into an assembly using Regex.CompileToAssembly method.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, select the Build menu and open the Configuration Manager. Look at the "Platform" column of the Project Contexts, and ensure that the selected platform for the project is x86, and that should ensure compilation to a 32-bit target.